# Selenium location method doesnt return the same type of coordinates for PyAutoGui

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui, webautomation

I want instead of using Selenium Actions to use PyAutoGui.

In the past I had the same problem with Java, the solution was to add offset on the "Y" axes because of the browser interface and the windows start bar. Now I have Offset on the "X" axes as well although I use chrome maximized. Also each element has a different offset.

```
def move_mouse(xpath) :
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    if elem.is_displayed() :
        x = elem.location.get('x')
        y = elem.location.get('y')
        print(x)
        print(y)
        pyautogui.moveTo(x,y,2)



chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.python.org/")
driver.maximize_window()
print("Window Size : "+ str(driver.get_window_size()))
time.sleep(2)
print("Window Position : "+str(driver.get_window_position()))
move_mouse('//*[@id="downloads"]/a')
```

Here is the output :

```
Window Size : {'width':1552, 'height': 840}
```

My screen resolution is 1920x1080, full screen mode gives the same results

```
Window Position : {'x' : -8, 'y': -8}
```

I can't understand why the window position is minus

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same after using "driver.maximize_window()" hope it's normal, if you use win + arrow up to maximasive window, you will get 'better' results.